# edit css page from asp.net code behind

Tags: html, css, asp.net, edit

I want to edit programmatically css file using asp.net's code behind, furthermore I tried some commands but without results.
to explain my situation: I should modify file.css (.class1 exist) from file.aspx.cs. For example add this proprety :

```
.class {backgroud-color:grey}
```

I made this:

```
<link href="file.css" rel="stylesheet" id="boxcss" runat="server" />
```

and in the code behind:

```
string iframe = "iframe{border-radius:300px}";
boxcss.Attributes.Add("class",iframe);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you modifying Css file? you can make Different Classes according to your requirement and then change your element's css class dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to add style attributes to the existing `.class1` selector or to create a new `.class2` selector:

```
Style class1 = new Style();
class1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(class1, null, ".class1");

Style class2 = new Style();
class2.BorderColor = Color.Red;
class2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
class2.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(5);
Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(class2, null, ".class2");
```

However, the Style class does not give access to `border-radius`. You can add that style attribute to the Header with the help of a Literal control:

```
Literal iframeStyle = new Literal();
iframeStyle.Text = "<style>iframe { border-radius: 300px; }</style>";
Header.Controls.Add(iframeStyle);
```

Note: The `head` tag must have the `runat="server"` attribute to be accessible in code-behind:

```
<head runat="server">
```